# C# Simple Coin flip algorithm not working

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my code, it should ask the user how many times they want to flip a coin and then proceed to flip that coin the stated number of times and then say how many heads and tails there were. The problem is that the program asks how many times the coin should be flipped and then just closes after user input. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int heads = 0;
    int tails = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Random coinflip = new Random();

    Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to flip a coin? ");
    counter = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        int flip = coinflip.Next(1, 3);
        if (flip == 1)
        {
           heads++;
        }
        else 
        {
           tails++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("You flipped a coin " + counter 
       + "times " + "and you got " + heads + "heads and " + tails + "tails.");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Add `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of `Main`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you can get rid of a whole variable `tails`. It's not needed since `tails = counter - heads`.

Comment: @RufusL that looks elegant, but doesn't seem to work. I ran it with 1000 tries and always the result is lopsided, normally 800ish vs 100ish heads to tails. I'm guessing because the normal Random() class is not _that_ random, and when the operations are too fast you get too many similar results.

Comment: Interesting! Well, one small optimization would be to pick a random number that's `0` or `1`, then inside the for loop would just be: `heads += coinflip.Next(0, 2);`

Comment: Yeah that's much better, both around 500.
Also on a side note, if I need more accurate random numbers especially in a fast loop I usually use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` in `System.Security.Cryptography` which is much better. [Here](https://gist.github.com/sachintha81/a4613d09de6b5f9d6a1a99dbf46e2385) is a working example if anyone would like to see.

Comment: I must add I found that in SO sometime ago, just don't have the link anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the final

```
Console.WriteLine()
```

to

```
Console.ReadKey()
```

That should keep the window open until you type a key, allowing you to see your output.